# How do I know that Apache Camel route has no more files to copy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am writing simple command line application, which copies files from ftp server to local drive. Lets assume that I am using the following route definition:

```
    File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("repo", "dat");
    IdempotentRepository<String> repository = FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(tmpFile);
    from("{{ftp.server}}") 
        .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"), repository)
        .to("file:target/download")
        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

where `ftp.server` is something like:

```
ftp://ftp-server.com:21/mypath?username=foo&password=bar&delay=5
```

Let's assume that files on the ftp server will not change over time. How do I check, whether the coping has finished or there are still some more file to copy? I need this, because I want to finish my app, once all file are copied.

Answer (score 1):

Read about batch consumer

- http://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html

The ftp consumer will set some exchange properties with the number of files, and if its the last file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the end that publishes the FTP files? E.g. is it your server and your client or can you make a request as a customer?

If so, you could ask for a flag file to be added at the end of their batch process. This is a single byte file with an agreed name that you watch for - when that file appears you know the batch is complete.

This is a useful technique if you regularly pull down huge files and they take a long time for a batch process to copy to disk at the server end. E.g. a file is produced by some streaming process.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over FTP file. They are provided by a third party.